# How to get type descriptor(JNI style) String from an TypeMirror object (annotation processing)

Tags: java, java-native-interface, annotation-processing, typedescriptor

I would like to get a String like:

```
Ljava/lang/Class;.getName()Ljava/lang/String;
```

(JNI style type/method description, or called type descriptor)

from an `javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror` object in an `AnnotationProcessor`. Is there any Convenience method or library, which parses the `TypeMirror` object and produces a String like above?

I would like to use the String to construct a 
`org.objectweb.asm.Type` object from the type descriptor string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize this is nearly a decade old, but I've written a library to add TypeMirror/Element support to the ASM library. See here: https://github.com/soabase/asm-mirror-descriptor - with this library you can now do:

```
MirrorClassReader reader = new MirrorClassReader(processingEnv, element);
reader.accept(myClassVisitor);  // standard ASM ClassVisitor
```

or

```
String signature = SignatureMirrorType.getSignature(processingEnv, element);
```

Answer (score -1):

Open console, go to your already compiled classes f.e. : cd ./build/classes . Then type javap -s NameOfYourCompiledClass.class (in console) and you'l get your descriptors. For your situation I'd extend this TypeMirror class with your custom class, overload all methods, compile the project and folow the instructions below for your new class

Comment: The question is how to programatically find the method descriptor from a TypeMirror instance, during annotation processing.